# Visual Studio intellisense not working

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

My Xamarin.Forms solution has 4 projects: PCL, Android, iOS, UWP.


I installed **sqlite-net-pcl** NuGet to all four projects.


I created an interface in the PCL project TestXam/Persistence/ISQLiteDb.cs

```
namespace TestXam.Persistence
{
    public interface ISQLiteDb
    {
        SQLiteAsyncConnection GetSQLiteAsyncConnection();
    }
}
```

I created a class in the Android project TestXam.Android/Persistence/SQLiteDb.cs

Now I type ": ISQLiteDb" next to the class name:

```
namespace TestXam.Droid.Persistence
{
    public class SQLiteDb : ISQLiteDb
    {

    }
}
```

**And nothing happens.

No red squiggly that would suggest me to add the using declaration.

Even when I add it manually, there is no squiggly that would warn me that I haven't implemented the interface.**

I reinstalled Visual Studio two times.

I deleted the project and started a new one.

All this to no avail.

**Is this a Visuao Studio bug or am I doing something wrong?**

::::::::::::::::::::: UPDATE :::::::::::::::::::::


Warning1:
IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.


Warning2:
The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll (v7.1) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v6.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.


Warning3:
The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for FormsViewGroup.dll (v7.1) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v6.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.


Warning4:
The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll (v7.1) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v6.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much kudoz to Juan Rodríguez, a.k.a. Juansero29, who's **[answer](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64860/visual-studio-erro)** explains how to solve this problem.


Just to re-iterate:

1. Set the Android project as the StartUp project.
2. Build it by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + B
3. Right click over the project and choose 'Unload Project'. (wait some seconds...)
4. Right click over the unload project again and choose 'Reload Project'.
5. Run the project and rejoice.